# Understand a python solution for Merge two sorted linked lists on HackerRank

Tags: python, linked-list

The problem is at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/one-week-preparation-kit-merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=preparation-kits&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-week-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-week-day-five

A solution is  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/one-week-preparation-kit-merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/forum

```
def join_lists(head1, head2):
    start_full_list = head1
    last_list1_node = head1
    while(last_list1_node.next != None):
        last_list1_node = last_list1_node.next
    last_list1_node.next = head2
    return start_full_list

def order_list(head):
    first_value = head
    while(first_value.next != None):
        second_value = first_value.next
        while(second_value != None):
            if (first_value.data > second_value.data):
                first_value.data, second_value.data = second_value.data, first_value.data
            second_value = second_value.next    
        first_value = first_value.next
    return head

def mergeLists(head1, head2):
    head_full_list = join_lists(head1, head2)
    head_full_list = order_list(head_full_list)
    return head_full_list
```

I have a couple of stupid questions:

1. about the node itself, it is said the node in the linked list is like a pointer; but python does not have a pointer type. Then, how does the node in python work? Does it somehow still associate with the address in memory?
2. in `def join_lists`, seems once `last_list1_node` connects the node.next, it will let `start_full_list` be the merged list. My question is, in the function `def join_lists`, why `last_list1_node` will somehow implement/finish `start_full_list`? Is that due to `=` is copy the memory address, hence, automatically connecting the nodes in `start_full_list`?

Comment: 1. Variables in Python only contain references (which are technically pointers) to objects. The node object contains a "next" attribute which contains a reference to another node object (or None).

Comment: 2. I have not fully understood this question but generally in the simple cases of the shown code the assignments just copy the references (usually implemented as memory addresses) from one variable to another.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if the question 2 is related to mutable/immutable aspect, such that `last_list1_node` will let `start_full_list` be a merged linked list. Sorry my thinking is not clear.

Comment: You should be asking only one question. Note that this algorithm is not efficient. It does not use the given information that the two input linked lists are **sorted**.